# framework give me error about cannot started directly

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, class-design

i created web project, and added new class library for framework. This framework includes DAL. But added reference . And running no this give me no fail.
runnig give me error:

" A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly

In order  to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project.
Set the executable project as the startup project "

please please help me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get this error because the project for the class library is chosen as the startup project in Visual Studio.  Right-click your web project and choose "Set as StartUp project".