# VS2012: Debug -> Start New Instance launches wrong project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

If I right click on a project in Solution Explorer, and select Debug->Start New Instance, then the compiler kicks in getting everything ready to run.  Good work so far.

However if during that compile I click within a source file that I happen to have open for editing, then the debugger attempts to launch the project that contains said source file!  Usually this results in it complaining that it can't launch a class of type library.

If I sit and wait patiently for the compiler to complete before launching then all is well.  But that's a bit annoying if I want to read some other code whilst it's compiling.

I'm working with C# and C++ in case that's important - you never know!

**Update**

The application that I want to launch is also selected as the startup project.  But then that shouldn't actually matter if I specifically select the application to be started.

Comment: What is your startup project? (Which project is in bold font). It has to be a web app or an executable

Comment: Might be worth looking at "[A project with output type of class library cannot be started directly - with a startup exe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/757010/1364007)" - seems like the same problem. I've had this before, BTW.

Comment: That's the one!  I'll go and read over there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

right click solution on solution explorer;

```
>> Common Properties
>>>> Startup Project
```

probably "Current selection" is selected . select other one of items

Comment: No, read the question again.  Also Wai Ha Lee has already provided links to sites telling me that this is a common issue.