# Windows Forms Control Library template

Tags: wpf, activex

we are trying to use an activex control from WPF to save a rewrite right now. Found this article , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735(v=vs.100).aspx that refers to the Windows Forms Control Library Template. now I have Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and there is no such template. Googled and just found pages with no usable content. was wondering if I could be pointed to where this exist or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Forms Control Library Template is a litte bit difficult to find. In my Visual Studio 2015 implementation I have it in the directory Visual C#\Windows\Classic Desktop. If you don't have this template, at least for Windows Forms you can also choose template Class Library and later change it in in such a way that you can use the Testcontainer when debugging your class library.

For how to achieve this see the post of Arnshea (6 upvotes) in this link [A project with output type of class library cannot be started directly - with a startup exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757010/a-project-with-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly-with-a). I have used his technique when I accidently used the wrong template when starting my projects.

Regards JRB