# "A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I downloaded a C# project and I wish to debug the project to see how an algorithm implementation works.

The project has come in a Folder, inside this folder there are -

1. **`.sln` file** and
2. **a folder which has source files and a `.csproj` file**.

I installed Visual Studio and opened the `.sln` file present in the main folder. I built the project successfully, but when I try to debug the project I get this message:

> A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project.

The strange part is that I don't see a main function anywhere.

What should I do to get round this hiccup?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

The project you have downloaded compiles into a dll assembly and provide a set of classes with implemented functionality.

You should add to your solution a new project with Output Type of either Console Application or Windows Application (VS Add Project wizard will offer you different templates of Projects).

In the newly added project, you can implement logic to test your Class Library.

Output type of the project you can find and change by the following steps:

1. Right click on project in Solution Explorer -> Properties.
2. In opened tab with properties select Application and there will be ComboBox marked with Output Type label.

Comment: And don‘t forget to set the newly created project as startup project (Right click on the new project↦Set as StartUp Project)

Comment: @bugybunny you comment is whats missing in the answer above!

Comment: I'm baffled!  I created a new solution containing a class.  I then added a Unit Test Project to the same solution, added a Windows Form to the test project, added references to the class in the unit test.  I then right-clicked and set the test project as the startup project.  The solution properties say that the unit test project is the single startup project. When I try to debug, I still see the same error message that the class can't be started directly.  What am I missing? (VS 2017).

Comment: Ah -- I found my error.  I had to set the application type for the Unit Test Project to a Windows Forms on the Application tab for the unit test project.

Comment: I've also created a new Console App project in my solution to stop this error from showing, and it does stop it, but I want to use the DLL from the Class Library in another project/CMS and uploaded it there but what I did isn't available...the DLL doesn't seem to have been built at all.

Answer (score 140):

Just right click on the Project Solution 
A window pops up.
Expand the common Properties.
Select Start Up Project

In there on right hand side Select radio button with Single Startup Project
Select your Project in there and apply.

That's it. Now save and build your project. Run the project to see the output.

Comment: This only works if the project's Output Type is not Class Library though right?

Comment: right-click on the Project Solution > select properties > A window pops up(solution property page), now you can see common Properties

Answer (score 92):

This was the solution that worked for me since I couldn't find 'Common Properties' option.

1. Select your topmost level project in *Solution Explorer*.
2. Go to Project, and in contextual menu *Set as StartUp Project*.

   [image: Set as StartUp Project]

See also: [A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11152272)

Comment: This worked for me also in VS 2015. It had to build me a new web.config, and then it was up and working again.

Comment: Worked for me in Visual Studio 2019 as well.

Comment: right-click on the Project Solution > select properties > A window pops up(solution property page), now you can see common Properties

Comment: that times when right click menu wont take entire screen height to display :)

Comment: This worked for me as well. After upgrading from VS2019 to VS2022, suddenly got this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

Just needs to go:

> Solution Explorer-->Go to Properties --->change(Single Startup project) from.dll to .web

Then try to debug it.

Surely your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 12):

> > The strange part is that I don't see a main function anywhere.

That is exactly your problem. The project merely creates a DLL.  It has no executable to run.

You will need to add a second project, which is an executable which references the other project, and calls something in it.

Comment: Hey James, Okay I have added a new project in the same solution. A new .cs file is created which has a main function. Now what should I reference to. To the dll you mean? When I right click on the references tab, I get a Add Reference window.

Comment: Navigate to the Projects Tab. There will be the set of assemblies defined in your solution available for referencing.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Don't forget to add specific usings to have ability of using classes of that library.

Answer (score 11):

```
1) Right Click on **Solution Explorer**
2) Go to the **Properties** 
3) Expand **Common Properties**
4) Select **Start Up Project**
5) click the radio button (**Single Start_up Project**)
6) select your Project name 
7) Then Debug Your project
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue when trying to use the Experimental Instance of Visual Studio 2013. This was for a vsix project (Creating Snippets).

Solution was:

**Right Click Project in Solution Explorer** > **Properties** > **Debug**

Setting the Start Action to `"Start external program"` and using the following path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

This option was set to `"Start project"` which won't work for the application output type Class Library, which caused that same error.

Note: Yours may differ depending on how you installed VS.

Answer (score 6):

```
    Right Click on "Solution Explorer" -> "Properties"
    Expand "Common Properties"
    Select "Start Up Project"
    click the radio button "Single Start_up Project"
    select your Project name from the drop down list.
```

If **still not working** after the above steps, then try this.

```
    Expand solutions explorer.
    Right click on project name -> "Properties"
    Go to "Application" tab
    Select "Output type" 
 From the drop down list select the appropriate type according to your application.
    "Windows application" or
    "Console application"
```

Then save (ctrl + S)

Try debugging (F5)

Answer (score 5):

You'll need some kind of app (Console Apps are my favorite for debugging, but a WinForm will do) which uses your Class Library.  Just add a new project (in the same solution) of a Console Application or Windows Forms Application, and add a reference to your current project.  Once you've done that, make any calls you need, set your break points, and go to town.

Answer (score 2):

Error solutions is that you have already open your project  but by mistake  you have selected another class library .. that's reason  this error is showing ... so what u need to do you u just select u r project then right click on u r project

after right click u can see the list box and select the "**Set as start up project** " option .

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer works if your solution has a project that compiles to an exe. If your solution does not have any projects that compile to an exe, then you have to use 'Start external program'.

VS2019 instructions:

1. right click -> properties on the main solution
2. debug, start external program, and add command line arguments

VS2022 instructions:

1. right click -> properties on the main solution
2. scroll down to Debug
3. Debug > General > Open debug launch profiles UI
4. left click the 'new' icon in the top left, select 'executable'
5. fill it out as per VS2019 (pick the exe and add command line arguments)
6. when clicking the start button, first select the profile you made

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have **multiple project** in the solution. Select the **project** that you want to view in browser and select **'Set as StartUp Project'**. In your multiple project soln which was the main, the visual studio was unable to identify. this was the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the Class Library project and from the drop-down choose Initialize Interactive C# which will load your project context and you can work it in the interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cause was that one of my projects in the solution wasn't loaded. The reason it couldn't load properly was that the file path length of one of the files was too long. Upon deleting this long file, I could reload the project, and build the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the question involves an Azure project, make sure you have the "Azure development" tool set installed, or when you go to run a solution you may get this same error.

Tools > Get Tools and Features... > Tick the box next to Azure development > Click install

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers provided above helped me resolve this error, this is what resolved the issue for me.

1. Right click on the solution and select "Properties", which is in my case "Sintctech.Data".
2. Select the section called "Application".
3. Check what you have selected as your output type. If it is "Windows Application", change it to "Console Appication".

[image]

4. Rebuild and the problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Right Click and choose properties on Library.
Output Type select console application.

Answer (score -1):

1- Double Click on csproj file

[image]

2- Convert “OutputType” label’s value from ‘Library’ to ‘exe’

[image]

3- select 'Set as StartUp Project'

[image]