# vb.net program debugging error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am trying to create a new library (.dll) for use in my SSIS project. I dont have any prior experience of creating these kind of projects. So please bear with me.

When I try to debug the program, it throws the following error 
[image]

What would be the best way to debug the following code. I know that it maybe wrong, but I am trying to learn this.

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports System.Net

'Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
'Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
'Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
'Imports System.IO
'Imports System.Net.Mail
'Imports System.Net

Public Class Logging
    Inherits LogProviderBase

End Class
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The screenshot that I posted is the error that I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just hit F5 and run a dll library.  It can only be used in another application.  You can Build the project and that will tell you if you have any obvious errors.

Most people have a test application that exercises there class library applications to give them an idea if there are any issues.

Similar questions : ["A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/c-a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)

Comment: To his point, you'll want to create another project in that solution and add a reference to it and import the namespace you'll want to use. Then you can test the stuff in your library.

Comment: Good Info: Thanks for adding this Yatrix