# Visual Studio: "Project with an output type class library cannot be started directly"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I checked out a solution consisting of two Visual Studio 2012 projects from a TFS repository. The first is a Visual Studio Add-In, the other project is a WPF User Control Library. As the library cannot be started directly, **I selected the AddIn as the StartUp project**. Nevertheless, I can't run it as it always reports

> Project with an output type class library cannot be started directly.

I get this error if I try to run the UserControl library alone, which is totally legit. But I definitely get the same error trying to start the AddIn. I have a project with exactly the same setup, which just works fine. My colleague does not have this problems to, working with the same TFS checkout.

There exist several threads concerning this question (like ["A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)) but I didn't find an answer there.

Any suggestions or ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)

Answer (score 1):

Add-ins can't be started directly either. You've set the add-in as the startup project on the solution. Now you need to go into the properties of the add-in project. Output type should be dll. Start action should be "start external program"
In the box, supply the path to VS, for me it's...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

Then command line arguments should be...

```
/resetaddin <YourAddInName>.Connect
```