# Cant debug a coded UI application in VS2012

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, coded-ui-tests

I am newbie in Coded UI testing. I am using VS2012 to create Coded UI test application. I am able to Build and Run the application.

However when I try to debug the project, it throws an error

*A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly.
In order to debug this project, add an executable project to the solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project*

I tried to add a console application to the project and follow the above process, but doesnt help.. :(

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2012 the big Debug button at the top of the window produces that message. To run or to debug a Coded UI test, right click in the source file of the test and select the `Run` or `Debug` entries.

In Visual Studio 2010 you could run or debug a Coded UI test using the buttons at the top of the window.