# error message after editing applicationhost.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After I updated some informatiion in applicationhost.config file(not actually add anything, I removed the lines I added and  changed it as default), after that when I launch my mvc web apps in vs2012, I got this error,

"A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly, In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project"

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)

Answer (score 1):

Are you pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>? If so, you must set the start-up project correctly. You will be to go to the solution explorer, right-click the MVC Web App and select "Set as StartUp project". See screenshot below...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please go to the solution explorer then right click the mvc project and click the "Set as Start up project" then run the project.

I hope your problem will be solved