# Visual Studio: A project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly in Release Mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

```
A project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly
```

I'm setting my solution to Release mode to test some functionality and this is the error I get. This is the settings I have and these work fine in Debug mode.

- Output Type: Class Library
- Startup Object: (Not set)

The error occurs after I set my solution to Release mode (clean and build performed). Here's what I have done so far.

- Changed the Output Type to Windows Application and Console Application
- Set the Startup Object to Program.cs
- Deleted .suo file

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in your solution? Seems like you have. And in Debug mode you have different start project rather than the one, which is of class library type.

Comment: Yes I have. I figured out that when I switch to release mode, it deletes the entry under Properties>Debug>Start External Program which points to another project. I have this working now, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that when I switch to release mode, it deletes the entry under:

- *Properties > Debug > Start External Program*

which points to another project. I have this working now.

-- [@jmc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848032/visual-studio-a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started#comment45964979_28848032)