# How to set up Start Project for Window.xaml WPF project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have created One project name called TestApp. I had created one Window.xaml file. In side I have created one button name called "Click Me!". When I try to set as start project and run the application i got below error message.

**Error Window:**

```
A project With an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly.

In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)

Answer (score 0):

You have created a class library project, so if you want to execute it, you have to create a WPF application and then reference that class library.

A class library isn't directly executable, because the compilation result is a .dll file instead of an .exe file.

If you want to know what type of project have you created, you can see it in properties.