# Create TaskPane in Outlook with NetOffice

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, netoffice

First things, I am a beginner in developing Add-Ins and I didn't find a good documentation for using NetOffice.

I have created an automation Addin project with the NetOffice Developer Toolbox. I want to create a TaskPane. When I start the project it throws the following exception:

> A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly.
>
> In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project.

May someone can tell me what is necessary to start the TaskPane.
[This is my Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBIXO.png)

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug the NetOffice addin project, you must change the Debug properties of the project in Visual Studio - set the **Start external program** to point to your installed MS Outlook EXE file.

If the add-in is correctly registered, you can debug the Task Pane.

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3363236