# C# - generate DLL linked in console App

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, console-application

I have two C# Applications

1. TestApp is a console app which call a method decrypt included in AppCrypt
2. AppCrypt contains this method and needs to log (write on a file)

So far I can modify TestApp and I saw the result on my console but my goal is to edit the code of AppCrypt

I am using VS for both.

Question 1) I cannot find where is written the place where I link the DLL of AppCrypt

Question 2) I can build AppCrypt but I cannot generate a new DLL because I am getting this message

[image]

I found on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3363236/1948785) that I should add a project Console App or a Winform but I just need to use that function without having a proper app so I dont know if it is my case.

I have built the DLL but it does not seems to be linked in my console app which is TestApp, how can I verify that it is linked?

Comment: You can _build_ a DLL, you just can't _run_ it directly.  You need some other project type (test, console, win, web, etc.) that _uses_ the library.

Comment: `I just need to use that function without having a proper app` Thats not how DLL works.

Comment: A Console application at least has a `Main()`. Running a DLL doesn't make much sense unless you know exactly what to run inside the DLL. I mean, there are a number of classes and methods into your DLL and Visual Studio doesn't know what you want to do with that.

Comment: "*I cannot find where is written the place where I link the DLL of AppCrypt*" In Visual Studio `Solution Explorer` (at your right) expand References node. These are saved into your project file.

Comment: @derloopkat, thank you there is a triangle in there how can I link my dll, I am very new to it

Comment: @eeadev, you can make quick progress by going on line and watching Youtube videos about Visual Studio and basic Console and Class Library projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error cause most probably you have set your class library project as `Startup project` in your solution. Whereas you should set the Console app as your start up.

How to Set a project as `StartUp`: Right click on your project name and from context menu select `Set As Startup Project`