# Debugging issue in Selenium Web driver project in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

[image]How to resolve this issue given in image and I want to debug my project but there is an message generated that "add executable project to this solution". Please help

Comment: You can not run the class file directly. Refer to this link for more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug and work with your Automation Selenium tests in Visual Studio. You can create the project as a :

1. Console App : You can use the run button to start the project and then apply breakpoints where ever you want to do the debugging
2. Create a Unit test project and then using the test explorer, debug/run the tests as you prefer.