# Cosmos basic example does not run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, operating-system, cosmos

I am trying to get started with Cosmos using C#. I installed Visual studio 2017, and Cosmos user kit. 
On many tutorials on youtube, I have seen that the VMWare player starts whenever they press the "run" button.

However, in my case, I get the following error: 
"A project with an Output type of class library cannot be started directly."

[image: Error screenshot]

My code is really simple, and it is the basic example given in the documentation. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Sys = Cosmos.System;

namespace CosmosKernel2
{
    public class Kernel : Sys.Kernel
    {
        protected override void BeforeRun()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cosmos booted successfully. Type a line of text to get it echoed back.");
        }

        protected override void Run()
        {
            Console.Write("Input: ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Text typed: ");
            Console.WriteLine(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)

Answer (score 2):

Cosmos is a kernel. You can't "run a kernel on windows". If you want to run your cosmos kernel straight out of Visual Studio you need a virtual machine.

Cosmos uses Vmware out of the box. Make sure you have it installed.
Alternatively you can use VirtualBox, I personally got it to run on that too.

You can also run it on an actual machine with a bootloader, like Grub. You can dual boot into windows or your own kernel that way.

Cosmos has instructions here: https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos/wiki/Deployment

Set the boot that cosmos generates as startup project to run it.

Comment: Hello, I have VMware player installed. In all the tutorials, when they click on the "run" button, VMWare pops up automatically. The problem is, this doesn't happen in my PC. I couldn't figure out a reason for that.

Comment: When you create a new Cosmos project with the visual studio template, it should generate a solution with 2 projects. <project name> and <projectname>boot. You need to set <projectname>boot as startup project by right-clicking it.