# VS “A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly”

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm novice in C#. I've cloned the project, built it successfully.
Now I want to debug `Postman` POST request.
I found the place where that request in handled in Project. That .cs file looks like this:

```
namespace Blah.Something
{
    public class SomethingRequest: IInterface
    {
        ...
        public object DoRequest (SomeRequest request)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

When I start `SomethingRequest` class, I have this error:
[image]

I've tried to set .csproj in which `SomethingRequest`  class is located as `"Set as a Startup Project"` as per suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly), and then rebuilt the solution, but I keep receiving same error. Can anyone help me to resolve that issue?

Comment: Please check here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly also shouldn't your inlet be at Main()?

Comment: _"I've cloned the project"_ - check the project's documentation for which project should be the startup project. Because you name PostMan, I guess you should look for a Web Application project.

Comment: @xTwisteDx , I already mentioned that I tried solution in that post and that didn't work, and I can't see Main there

Comment: You can't run a dll. You must create a project targetting an executable or a web site that uses this dll

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly)

Comment: @StephenKennedy , please read post first, I'm referring to that post , saying that didn't help. If that post didn't help, this can't be a duplicate

Answer (score -1):

You can't run the classlibrary directly.
I have two solutions and you may refer to it.

First, Please create a new project(such as console app) to call the method in that library.

Like the following:

Classlibrary:

```
namespace Testlibrary
{
  public  class Student
    {
        public void SayHello(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, I am {0}",name);
        }
    }
}
```

Console app:(Please add reference)

```
using System;
using Testlibrary;

namespace _1.Test_for_using_library
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student s = new Student();
            s.SayHello("Jack");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Second, you can change the classlibrary to the console app to call the method.

Right click the Classlibrary->Properties-> Change Output type to Console Application -> Add the following code in the Student Class.

```
static void Main()
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.SayHello("Jack");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Finally, you will the same result as the before.