# Visual Studio Class Library cannot be started directly

Tags: visual-studio

Project was runned without problem before but now IDK why ı got this error. I did everything typed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363106/a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly/74576444#74576444) and couldnt solve it. Also ı try to run other project but ı got same error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I try to Clean&Build solution its worked.